# Task Scheduler Last Run Result (0x8000808C)

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

What is the last run (**0x8000808c**) code mean in the windows task scheduler?

I checked all the references [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-error-and-success-constants?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but this code doesn't exist.

I have no idea if the task was successful or not. The event history shows it was successfully executed but the data related to it doesn't reflect to it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-error-codes.md

Answer (score 1):

This code **(0x8000808C)** is because the program or script that the task calls did not run correctly, the suggestion not only for this error code but for all others is to use the **Event Viewer**.

Open the **Event Viewer**, in my case the task ran an application so I opened Event Viewer, expanded **Windows Logs** -> **Application**, searched for the application name and there was the error, in my case the problem was with the ASP.NET version Core Runtime.